# ¿Por qué sucede el error?

Tags: excel, vba

Bueno estoy tratando de recorrer una hoja de excel desde la última fila a la primera, para eliminar las filas que en la columna H contengan un valor de "VERDADERO", hasta el momento esta así:

```
For i = numRows To 2 Step -1
    Cells(i, H).Select
    If Cells(i, H) = "VERDADERO" Then
         ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
         Selection.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Pero el valor de numRows al ser de 87057 genera un error, alguien sabe de que otra manera puedo hacer este proceso?

Comment: La pregunta no está clara. Cuando ocurren mensajes de error, deben de incluirse en mensaje de error textual. Mas detalles en [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente el error esta en que el tipo de dato que le asignaste a numRows es entero; verifica que sea almenos de tipo long o double.

Ademas no especificas como calculaste dicha variable, te comparto una alternativa:

```
 Dim lastrow as double
 lastrow=application.count(Range("A:A"))+1 'Suponiendo que la columna A sea de tipo numerica y no tenga espacios vacios
for i=lastrow to 2 step -1
If Cells(i, H) = "VERDADERO" Then
         rows(i).entirerow.delete
end if
 next i
```

Ademas Habría que analizar si lo que buscas es la cadena de caracteres "VERDADERO" o el valor lógico VERDADERO